# Jmeter - Android Mobile Application Recording

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

while recording Mobile Application. Trafic is not going via Proxy.

I have installed CA certificate in Android App.

Jmeter is recording but recording only Certain URLs and Other URLS like Google, Appstore are not been recorded including my Mobile APP (App under test,SUT).

I am unable to Login in to the APP aswell when i set Proxy in mobile App (under Manual)

```
Jmeter : V.5.1
Android : 9
JDK: 13
```

Mobile Application has Microsoft Login credentials.

Response I get is  SSL handshake :  certificate_Unknown and I get  :`443 Error Response`.

can any one Help me with this issue .

Comment: Thank you for editing @Mehrdad Pedramfar

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [Android 7.0 (Nougat)](https://www.android.com/versions/nougat-7-0/) you need to perform some specific [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) in order to use self-signed [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) certificates (inluding JMeter's one)

1. Under [application](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element) section of your application [manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/) add the next line:

   ```
   android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
   ```
2. Under [`res` folder](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) create the `network_security_config.xml` file and put the following code there:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <network-security-config>
       <debug-overrides>
           <trust-anchors>
               <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
               <certificates src="user"/>
           </trust-anchors>
       </debug-overrides>
   </network-security-config>
   ```
3. [Build your application in debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode)

   ```
   gradlew assembleDebug
   ```
4. That's it, now you should be able to capture your application secure traffic with JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder. Check out [Recording Using Android Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices) article for more details if needed

---

Other options are:

1. If your application can be built for Android < 7.0 you can use the device or [emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator) - it will be quite enough to just install `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file there
2. If you have [rooted](https://www.androidcentral.com/root) device or emulator - you can add the JMeter's certificate into [Android trusted CA](https://awakened1712.github.io/hacking/hacking-install-ca-android/)

Comment: thank you @Dimitri T. I shall try and get back to you .

Comment: Hello @Dmitri T and others.

I have tried to do some steps as recommended by you and Blazemeter , but Still unable to login in to the Mobile App .  Jmeter still throws SSL handshake Error. 

Just wanted to update with info.

My Mobile app talks to Backend Server  and I get the below Error 

[link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670625/trying-to-record-a-mobile-application-through-jmeter-where-it-is-showing-443-er

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T

Tried to do same steps as recommended by you and Blazemeter , but Still unable to login in to the Mobile App .  

Followed Steps 1,2,3  and Step 4 we get debug mode app in C#,VS
Jmeter still throws SSL handshake Error. 
Just wanted to update with some extra info.
My Mobile Android App is Xamarin ,Hybrid App. 
My Mobile app talks to Backend Server  
Cannot log into mobile & lost of internet connection & gives below Error as this 

[link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670625/trying-to-record-a-mobile-application-through-jmeter-where-it-is-showing-443-er